# Multiple and's in if python statement

Tags: python, web-scraping, conditional-statements, simplify

I'm writing a python crawler that would find contact links in a given page's urls. However, my if statement looks nasty:

```
if 'news' not in link and 'archive' not in link and 'download' not in link and 'career' not in link and '././' not in link and '..' not in link and '../' not in link and 'store' not in link and 'mailto' not in link and 'tel:' not in link and '.pdf' not in link:
```

There has to be a better way to do this. Especially because as I go through more and more sites, I'll add more rules as to what the url can contain.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
excluded = ['news', 'archive', ]

if all(part not in link for part in excluded):
```

or [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if not any(part in link for part in excluded):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can be clever and use `all` and list comprehensions

```
checks = ['foo', 'bar']

link = ['something']

if all(k not in link for k in checks):
   #do something
```

`all` returns `True` if all items in the given list are `True`

`any` returns `True` if any items in the given list are `True`

Example:

```
>>> l0 = [False, False]
>>> any(l0)
False
>>> all(l0)
False
>>> l1 = [True, False]
>>> any(l1)
True
>>> all(l1)
False
>>> l2 = [True, True]
>>> any(l2)
True
>>> all(l2)
True
```

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list to store your match patterns instead check all of those in a single condition. E.g.

```
link = 'https://example.com/news'
matchings = ['news', 'archive', 'etc']
for match in matchings:
    if not match in link:
        do_something()
        break
```

Comment: That doesn't does the same thing, it will run `do_something` multiple times for each `match` not found

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately this doesn't work since I want to make sure that none of the matching keywords are in the url. So for example with the link provided, it would run false on the first run (because 'news' is in the link), but on the second run it will run true and mark the link as valid which isn't what I want to happen in the app. Thanks for your time though!